# Is there any layout orientation in android like this

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-linearlayout

The linear layout in android is like this...
[Layout available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5v26.jpg)

But I want a layout that will move the inner widget down instead of forward like this
[Layout I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeaWP.jpg)

Comment: I used FlexboxLayout for similar things https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

Comment: Why is this needed? you may use RelativeLayout or ConstraintLayout for this view.

Answer (score 0):

there is no layout in Android, which can do such replacing, but you can use [`Flexbox` lib from Google](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only use linear layout then you can do nesting of 2 linear layout
in 1 : orientation will be vertical, and horizontal in other

To make it more easy, use relative/constraint layout.